# Writing the xpath for the below code

Tags: html, xpath

Below is a code snippet from one of my project for which I need the xpath of a certain element.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-5 text-right boldText">Service Group Id:</div>
         <div class="col-md-5 ng-binding">436095</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need the xpath for 436095 element.But, the class is same for some other elements, so I can't use the same and the text is also different. So i wanted a generic solution and used the xpath as

```
//div[contains(text(),"Service Order Id:")]/../div[2]
```

But this doesn't work. Kindly suggest me a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the text is `Service Group Id`, not `Service Order Id`. And, you can use the [`following-sibling` notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling):

```
//div[contains(., "Service Group Id")]/following-sibling::div
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below xpaths. It will work for you.

```
//div[@class='row']/child::div[2]
//div[@class='col-md-5 text-right boldText']/following-sibling::div    
//div[contains(.,'Service Group Id:')]/following-sibling::div
```